# Laravel form request validation return error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation, laravel-formrequest

i'm using laravel form request validation to validate a request from view to controller. i'm using `php artisan make:request SpecializedRequest`. but when the validation fail it doesn't return back and it gave error 422. i've looked up at [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-xhr-requests-and-validation) and i don't really understand it. How do i make sure if the validation fail it return back to previous page with error message
my Form Request validation

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Specialized\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Modules\Specialized\Entities\Specialized;

class SpecializedRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the error messages for the defined validation rules.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'name.required' => 'Nama Specialized cannot be empty',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

my controller

```
/**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     * @param  SpecializedRequest $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store(SpecializedRequest $request)
    {
        $specialized = Specialized::create($request->validated());
        return ($specialized) ? back()->withSuccess('Data has been added') : back()->withError('Something wrong') ;
    }
```

my blade

```
<form action="{{ route('specialized.store') }}" method="{{ $method }}" class="form-horizontal">
    @csrf   
    <fieldset class="content-group">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="control-label col-lg-2">Name</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="{{ old('name',isset($specialized->name) ? $specialized->name : '') }}">
                <span style="color:red;"> {{$errors->first('name')}} </span>
            </div>
        </div>

    </fieldset>


    <div class="text-right">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit <i class="icon-arrow-right14 position-right"></i></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

tried this same result

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
        ]);
        $specialized = Specialized::create($data->validated());
        return ($specialized) ? back()->withSuccess('Data has been added') : back()->withError('Something wrong') ;
    }
```

Comment: 422 is the validation error response ... how are you sending this request?

Comment: @lagbox thru blade, via route normally i've update my post and add my blade

Comment: the fact it is returning a 422 and not doing the redirect would mean it thinks this is some type of ajax request or something that is expecting json back

Comment: @lagbox but i'm not, i'm using nwidart laravel module if it's important though

Comment: also, why are you reading the Laravel 8 docs if you are using some version of Laravel 5?

Comment: @lagbox i tried move the validation to the controller, same thing it said error 422, about laravel 8 and 5 it kinda give me same thing not all same but what i need is same

Comment: what version are you using? use the docs for the version you are using

Comment: my laravel 5.6 @lagbox

Comment: @lagbox i kinda solved it. if i use .`Validator::make($request,$rules)` it worked. now how do i use `Validator::make` on `SpecializedRequest`

Answer (score 0):

What version of laravel are you working with?

I don't think you need:

```
$specialized = Specialized::create($request->validated());
```

Try:

```
$specialized = Specialized::create($request->all());
return redirect()->back() ;
```

Then handle error display in your blade, something like:

```
@if($errors->any()){{ implode('', $errors->all('<div>:message</div>')) }}@endif
```

Also, I believe you need:

```
    /**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}
```

in your SpecializedRequest.

I hope this helps.

Comment: my laravel 5.6, and i've tried and it same result

Comment: try `php artisan view:clear` and `composer dump-autoload`. Then try again. You should at least get a different response.

Comment: same thing, but i kinda solved it. if i use .`Validator::make($request,$rules)` it worked. now how do i use `Validator::make` on `SpecializedRequest`